# How can I manually install SVN connectors in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I've been using early versions of the new Eclipse (3.7 and 4.0) and they have been quite stable, however I am missing SVN support.

Using the prescribed (for the stable version 3.6) method of using the eclipse update site, I cannot install a connector because the available versions are not supported. I have read of other users successfully using the connectors after installing them manually, however I cannot find any description of how to do this.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

Did you try the <del>http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/2.0/update-site/</del>  site, listed on [the Polarion Subversive site](http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/subversive/download.php?utm_source=eclipse.org&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=subversive)?

**Update**: A -1 given to this answer made me realize that the update site URLs are changed. The current list of update sites is the following:

<del>* http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/2.0/builds/ – Subversive Connector Archives for Subversive 0.</del>
<del>* http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/builds/ – Subversive Connector Archives for Subversive 1.0/1.1</del>

Additionally, if the update site urls have changed again, consult the Polarion site.

**Update**

New Urls are:

- Subversive Plugin: https://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/4.8/release/latest/
- Subversive Connector Plugin: https://osspit.org/eclipse/subversive-connectors/

Comment: Can anyone upload connectors for 6.0?! Their page is always down!!

Answer (score 6):

This is the new link for downloading SVN Connector manually.

https://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/neon-site/

Open Eclipse>>help>> Install Software>>Paste the above url>>click add>>Select the connector>>now install.

The above url is subjected to change so please visit this link for latest link:
https://www.polarion.com/products/svn/subversive/download

Comment: Please update the links if they are further changed.